# Python CSV file to bytes or seekable file-like object

Tags: python, csv, aws-lambda, boto3

Background: using python inside of an AWS Lambda to send a csv file to an s3.

Issue: Cannot get Boto3 to accept my csv file or a csv.reader object.

Example:

```
# writing to csv file
with open('/tmp/' + output_file_name, 'a+') as csvfile:
    for row in csv_reader:
        # ... do data manipulation
        csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)

# read and send to s3
with open('/tmp/' + output_file_name, 'r') as file:
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_client.put_object(Body=file, Bucket='bucket-output', Key=output_file_name)
```

I receive the error `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`. So I tried to open the file to read with param `encoding='utf-8'` but no luck there..

What needs to be done for Boto3 to 'accept' a csv file?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense... `for row in csv_reader: .... csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)`????

Comment: "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing." *are you using Python 2*? Otherwise that's a pretty out of date error message

Comment: In any case, adding `encoding='utf-8'` isn't going to fix that error, rather, open the file in `'rb'` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me to read a csv from a local drive and upload to s3

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().decode('utf-8')

boto3.client('s3').put_object(Body=data, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Comment: This works! What I was missing was 'rb' to read the file in as bytes. And thank you for simplifying my boto3 lines into one!